# How to read user input in ATS?

Tags: ats

In my ATS application, I am trying to read a input string from a user.
Is there any function in ATS that performs similar functionality as scanf function in C.. If not how to get the input from user without integrating ATS with JS or HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to read from STDIN:

```
#include
"share/atspre_staload.hats"
#include
"share/HATS/atspre_staload_libats_ML.hats"

implement
main0() =
{
//
val
lines =
streamize_fileref_line(stdin_ref)
//
val () = lines.foreach()(lam x => println! (x))
//
} (* end of [main0] *)
```

Comment: how is this compiled? `patscc -DATS_MEMALLOC_LIBC -latslib file.dats -o file` gives me an undefined reference to `atspre_fileref_get_line_string_main2`

Answer (score 1):

If you compile to C, then scanf is available. Here is a simple example:

```
#include
"share/atspre_staload.hats"
#staload
"libats/libc/SATS/stdio.sats"

implement
main0() =
{
//
var str1 = @[char][1024]()
var str2 = @[char][1024]()
//
val () = println! ("Enter name: ")
val ec = $extfcall(int, "scanf", "%s", addr@str1)
val () = assertloc (ec != 0)
val str1 = $UNSAFE.cast{string}(addr@str1)
//
val () = println! ("Enter your website name: ")
val ec = $extfcall(int, "scanf", "%s", addr@str2)
val () = assertloc (ec != 0)
val str2 = $UNSAFE.cast{string}(addr@str2)
//
val () = println! ("str1 = ", str1)
val () = println! ("str2 = ", str2)
//
}
```

Comment: The above code works but why var _ = print (str[0]) does not work ?

Comment: Because str[0] could be out-of-bounds if str is empty. Please try to use combinators to process strings.